# Copy all non-text files

Tags: cp

I need to move all files not ending with the .txt, .cpp, and .h extensions in one folder to a seperate folder via the cp command.

Is there a built in way to do this or do I need to make a script?

Comment: I get a syntax error running that command, relating to the "(" character... I'm sorry but I'm not familiar enough with the find command to debug this myself.

Comment: Oh looks like that's missing, somehow it didn't copy over with the trusty ctrl+c ctrl+v? I'll try again and if it works let you know so you can make a proper answer and I can accept it for you.

Comment: Hey it works! Feel free to leave a proper answer!

Comment: I know lol, it was throwing an error, however it still did the job it was supposed to do, so that's good enough for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It all depends on the robustness you need. Some of these ideas (e.g. -print0) aren't available on all systems, so YMMV.

## Quick, one-time need for few files:

1. `mkdir .tmp`
2. `mv *.txt *.cpp *.h .tmp`
3. `mv * /separate_folder/`
4. `mv .tmp/* .`
5. `rmdir .tmp`

Of course it's a hack, but it won't chew up I/O, it takes only a few seconds to whip off, and is portable.

## For processing many files:

`find . -maxdepth 1 -type f ! -name '*.txt' ! -name '*.cpp' ! -name '*.h' -print0 | xargs -0 mv -t /separate_folder/`

If your filenames don't contain spaces or other oddball characters, you can probably get away with omitting the `-print0` and `-0` (and thus relying on the default `-print` logic).

## If using Bash

See the Bash man page regarding the `GLOBIGNORE` variable "to restrict the set of filenames matching a pattern", as well as the `!(pattern-list)` which "Matches anything except one of the given patterns".